# How do I call this javascript function?

Tags: javascript

As documented here: http://www.jblotus.com/2011/05/24/keeping-your-handlebars-js-templates-organized/

I am trying to use this function:

```
(
    function getTemplateAjax(path, callback) {
        var source;
        var template;

        $.ajax({
            url: path,
                success: function(data) {
                    source    = data;
                    template  = Handlebars.compile(source);    

                    //execute the callback if passed
                    if (callback) callback(template);
            }
        });
    }

    //run our template loader with callback
    (getTemplateAjax('js/templates/handlebarsdemo.handlebars', function(source) {
        //do something with compiled template
        $('body').html(template);
    })()
)()
```

I am new to JS, so how can I use this?

I am trying to:

1. pass the path of the handlebars file
2. pass a json object which will be inserted in the template and an html should be returned back by the functions.

**Update:**

Got the answer, there was a typo in the code: this works.

While calling the function, the argument was source but was being used as template.

```
function getTemplateAjax(path, callback) {
    var source;
    var template;

    $.ajax({
        url: path,
            success: function(data) {
                source    = data;
                template  = Handlebars.compile(source);    
                if (callback) callback(template);
        }
    });
}

getTemplateAjax('js/templates/handlebarsdemo.handlebars', function(template) {
    data = {title: "hello!" , body: "world!"}
    $('body').html(template(data));
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is correct and you seem to be calling it correctly.
You should make sure that you have jQuery properly setup (just check the value of the jQuery global variable - it should not be "undefined").
Also, you should check if the handlebars really is where you think it is - maybe you should be using an absolute URL instead of a relative one.

Comment: I just don't dont know how to use the above functions, very new to js. What does it return and how can I call this? When I put this whole code in <script> tag, I get errors

Answer (score 0):

First try to check whether your are goint in that function or not. If you are then check you are getting response from ajax call or not... and use try...exception - so that if something wrong in ajax setting you know it straightaway.

You can show results only if you do get the results back from your ajax call.